# PHP cookie name does not accept space values

Tags: php, cookies

```
<?php
include 'lastfive.php';
cal('2016 Trek 8.4 DS');
$product7="2016 Trek 8.4 DS";

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$product7])) {
$value=1;
  echo "Cookie named '" . $product7 . "' is not set!";
setcookie($product7, $value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
} 


 else {
  echo "Cookie '" . $product7 . "' is set!<br>";
  echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$product7];
$value=$_COOKIE[$product7]+1;
setcookie($product7, $value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
?>
```

This code does not set a cookie. when i remove the space and the '.' the cookie is set. Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 4):

> cookie name is a kind of variable name. So it will not support any
>   character which is not allowed for variable name.

Comment: suppose if i want to link a url to it how do i do it?

Comment: `setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly)` see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) @sachinhunur

Comment: suppose i set a cookie like this setcookie("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600, "www.example.com");      how do i access the domain value in $_COOKIE ??

Comment: You can't get anything but `value` from `cookie`. If you need to pass `url` than set another `cookie` and pass the `url` as `value`. @sachinhunur